Python loop to copy every value in a column to the row underneath it in a Pandas dataframe
I am new to Pandas and wanted to see if someone could help with providing a loop in Python to copy a cell value in a row to the cell underneath it in the same column?
I have tried making a for loop but havent had much luck getting it to work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

also provide an example of input/output

Your question is not fully clear, but assuming:

Is there a way to have this set up so that every odd cell value is dropped underneath itself? Essentially row 1 is 2, 3 is 4, 5 is 6, etc.

And this input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(7)})

#    col
# 0    0
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    3
# 4    4
# 5    5
# 6    6

You can slice the odd rows and reassign the shifted DataFrame (with loc + shift):
df.loc[1::2] = df.shift(-1).loc[1::2]

Alternatively, if you don't have NaNs, you could also slice, then ffill:
out = df.loc[::2].reindex(df.index).ffill()

Output:
   col
0    0
1    2
2    2
3    4
4    4
5    6
6    6


You're welcome, you could consider editing your question to add a clear example (you can copy mine). This will be useful to future readers of the question

Suppose that you have the "df" and you want to pass all the values of the dataframe to underneath (you can after it choose just one column).
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for col in df.columns:
    for i in range(len(df) - 1):
        df.at[i + 1, col] = df.at[i, col]

Another solution is to use the shift method on pandas:
df_shifted = df.shift(1)

df_concatenated = df[['column_you_want']].copy()
df_concatenated['A_shifted'] = df_shifted['column_you_want']


The for loop you provided made all of the rows turn into the first row that was copied. Is there a way to have this set up so that every odd cell value is dropped underneath itself? Essentially row 1 is 2, 3 is 4, 5 is 6, etc..

@user23666463 please edit your question to provide a [mre]
